# How Can I Access Largest Image Size with Instagram Multiple Images (Carousel)

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

When Instagram posts have a single image, I can access the largest-size image by using the following URL format:

https://instagram.com/<POST_ID>/media/?size=l (lowercase "L")

But I have not found any documentation of how to configure a URL to access the largest size of other images, besides the first. (When accessing a post that uses a carousel, the URL configuration above only accesses the first image.)

Is there a way to do that? So far I've only found a way to access a JSON using the URL format:

https://instagram.com/<POST_ID>/media/?__a=1

The JSON contains nodes with typename "GraphImage" which contain links to the largest size for the successive images.

But is there some way to get to those images without access to the JSON, knowing only the post ID?